Area of a Rectangle From the Definition of Area Found in a Multivariable Calculus Textbook
The book is Multivariable Calculus by Peter Lax and Maria Terrell. First some background.
Let $D$ be a bounded region in the plane and let $h>0$. Divide the whole plane into squares
of side length $h$ by the lines $x = kh$ and $y = mh$, where $k$ and $m$ are integers.
Let $N_L(D,h)$ be the number of $h$-squares that are contained in $D$, and let $A_L(D,h)$ be the area of the union of all these $h$-squares. Therefore,
$$A_L(D,h) = h^2 N_L(D,h).$$
If we set $h=1/2^{n}$, then $A_L(D,1/2^{n})$ defines an increasing sequence that is bounded above. By the monotone convergence theorem this sequence has a limit, call it $A_L(D)$.
Similarly, define $N_U(D,h)$ to be the number of $h$-squares that intersect $D$, and let $A_U(D,h)$ be the area of the union of all these $h$-squares. Setting $h=1/2^n$ we see that $A_U(D,1/2^n)$ defines a decreasing sequence that is bounded below. By the monotone convergence theorem this sequence has a limit, call it $A_U(D)$.
If $A_L(D) = A_U(D)$, this common value is denoted by $A(D)$ and we say that $D$ has area.
To show that this is an adequate definition of area one of the things the authors show is that the area of a rectangle whose edges are parallel to the $x$ and $y$ axes is the
product of the lengths of the edges of the rectangle. It doesn’t matter if all,
some, or none of the boundary points are included in the rectangle.
I get stuck when trying to follow the beginning of their argument.
Let $R$ be the rectangle $[a, b] \times [c, d]$. Then when $h < \min\{b-a,d-c\}$ the number of $h$-squares that meet the boundary of $R$ does not exceed twice the perimeter divided by $h$. However, is it not also true that the number of $h$-squares that meet the boundary of $R$ does not exceed the perimeter $P$ divided by $h$? If so, using twice the perimeter creates a trivially weaker inequality. Next they state that this implies the inequality
$$0 \leq (b-a)(d-c) - A_L(R,h) \leq \frac{4((a-b)+(d-c))}{h}h^2 = 2Ph.$$
I am confused about how this inequality is established.
If we know that $A(R)$ exists and that $A(R) = (b-a)(d-c)$, then because $A(R)$ is the least upper bound it follows that for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists an $h>0$ such that $$ A(R)- A_L(R,h) \leq \epsilon.$$
But since we don't know that $A(R)$ exists, the inequality seems to have come out of thin air. If we were to divide everything by $h^2$ the quantity
$$\frac{(b-a)(d-c) - A_L(R,h)}{h^2} = \frac{(b-a)(d-c)}{h^2} + N_L(R,h)$$
must somehow represent the number of $h$-squares that meet the boundary of $R$, but I cannot see it.

Perhaps the author is describing the squares as closed regions (including their boundaries), an edge of the rectangle might lie precisely on a horizontal line dividing two rows of squares (analogously for a vertical line and columns of squares). In this case the count of squares would be twice what you expect generically.

You are right; the squares are considered to be closed. That answers my first question. Thank you!
